# Filtering files by source with Automator

Tags: finder, applescript, automator

I want to sort my Downloads folder and want to use Automator for it. The `Files & Folders` library gives me plenty of options, **however I was not able to find an action which let me filter files by their source.**

> I want to sort files by the URL I downloaded them from. Is there an
>   Automator action I am missing? Or do I have to use Apple Script for
>   that?

The `Filter Finder Files` gives me the options for filtering by name, date etc., but not by source. How can I accomplish this task?

Comment: What is the real end goal here?

Comment: @user3439894 I want to say "PDFs downloaded from URL contains "bankname" move to folder "banking""

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, 'I want to say "PDFs downloaded from URL contains "bank name" move to folder "banking"', here is how I'd do it in **Automator**:

In **Automator**, create a new *Workflow*, adding the following *Actions*:

**Find Finder Items**, with settings:

- Search [Downloads]
- [All] of the following are true
- [Kind] [is] [PDF]

**Run Shell Script**,  with settings:

- Shell [/bin/bash]
- Pass input [as arguments]
- Replace the default *code* with the example *code* below.

  ```
  for f in "$@"; do
      [[ $(mdls -name kMDItemWhereFroms "$f") == *bankname* ]] && echo "$f"
  done
  ```
- **Note:** In the *code* above, replace "*bankname*" in `*bankname*` with the actual *bank name* in the **URL**.

**Move Finder Items**, with settings:

- To [Banking]   [] Replacing existing files

  - Check Replacing existing files if appropriate.